# How to change background image depending on the document height?

Tags: nuxt.js, background-image

In a Nuxt app in default layout in `mounted()` I made a function which changes the background of div depending on the height of the document. I seems to work but the image doesn't show and I get this error:

GET [http://192.168.0.248:3000/~/assets/backgrounds/t%C5%82oG%C5%82%C3%B3wne/imgonline-com-ua-twotoone-Nfp0IIoBqH02gs.jpg](http://192.168.0.248:3000/%7E/assets/backgrounds/t%C5%82oG%C5%82%C3%B3wne/imgonline-com-ua-twotoone-Nfp0IIoBqH02gs.jpg) 404 (Not Found)

I have checked and there is no error in the name of the image. I tied also to to it insted of `~` - `./`

My `template`:

```
<template>
<div class="web-app">
    <div>
        <Navbar></Navbar>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <Nuxt/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <Footer/>
    </div>
</div>
```

My code in `mounted()` looks like that:

```
mounted() {
    let main = document.querySelector('.web-app');
    if (document.body.scrollHeight > window.innerHeight) {
        main.style.backgroundImage = 'url("~/assets/backgrounds/tłoGłówne/imgonline-com-ua-twotoone-Nfp0IIoBqH02gs.jpg")';
        // main.style.backgroundSize = 'contain';
    } else {
        main.style.backgroundImage = 'url("~/assets/backgrounds/tłoGłówne/4853433.jpg")'

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `require` to load any backgroundImage to an element.
But I don't think that you can do that dynamically, at least what I've tried is not working so far.

So here is a solution to make it in some way by toggling between both images.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="toggle">toggle them</button>
    <div
      v-if="firstImage"
      class="w-72 h-24"
      :style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${require('@/static/first.png')})` }"
    ></div>
    <div
      v-else
      class="w-72 h-24"
      :style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${require('@/static/second.png')})` }"
    ></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      firstImage: true,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.firstImage = !this.firstImage
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

You could then toggle it rather depending of `document.body.scrollHeight > window.innerHeight`.
Btw, I think that maybe [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) may be a better fit here.